# Como cambio donde quiero subir mi proyecto git?

Tags: git, github

Tengo un proyecto en un github pero quiero también subir otro proyecto diferente a git, como puedo hacer para que esté cada uno vinculado a un proyecto distinto en github?

Comment: Es decir ¿dos carpetas con proyectos distintos en tu perfil de github?

Comment: Si tienes los proyectos en carpetas locales separadas, y cada una es un repositorio `git` local, basta que asignes en cada una un `remote` diferente. La forma más simpe puede ser crear un proyecto vacío en Github y seguir las instrucciones que él te da para "subir un repositorio existente".

Comment: Otra forma es cambiar el .gitconfig

Comment: Como asigno un remote diferente? @abulafia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que no esta creado el repositorio en github, hay que crearlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el menu que te sale para crear el repositorio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aqui es donde te explica como hacer lo que quieres hacer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resumiendo es esto:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/MIUsuario/MiRepo.git
git push -u origin master
```

Pero si sigues los pasos github te rellena todo con los nombres correctos.

Comment: Lo conseguí! Muchas gracias! por las fotos y todo

Answer (score 0):

1) Crear el nuevo **repositorio remoto** en github (o gitlab, bitbucket, etc)

2a) Ahora localmente, si ya tienes archivos o no, debes usar el comando `git init` para crear el **repositorio local**, luego puedes añadir tus archivos iniciales con `git add, git commit`. En este punto haces el enlace entre tu repo local y remoto con el comando `git add remote <NOMBRE_REMOTO> <URL_REMOTO>`. Ya está listo para hacer `push, fetch, pull`

2b) Si es un repositorio git existente solo debes usar `git add remote <NOMBRE_REMOTO> <URL_REMOTO>`